# Manipulate jquery menu on re-size for responsive layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

There is simple menu with list itmes. UL LI. width and numbers of LI is dynamic. And there is dropdown kind of thing "more" on hover/click it will show remaining LI , which will not fit available space.

I tried using jquery while user resize windows from right to left, it will hide the last visible menu item. What is the possible way to do this revers and also add LI in "more" link.

Tried some option, as width is less when we resize then list item move below and increase height of UL so using this method I am able to hide last visible.
code

http://jsbin.com/flexmenu/2/edit

**Step 1**

[image: resize of window]

**Step 2**[image]

**Step 3**[image]

These steps will be reverse when user re-size (increase the width)

Markup

```
<div class="twelve columns filter-wrapper">
    <ul class="nav-bar-filter" id="nav-bar-filter">
        <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Small</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Medium</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Extra large</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Small-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Medium-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Extra large text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Large text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    </ul>
<ul id="more-nav">
  <li><a href="#">More > </a>
    <ul class="subfilter"><li><a href="#">Text</a></li></ul>
  </li>    
</ul>
</div>
```

Basically this menu will be used for responsive layout menu.Any help in this will be helpful.
Edit 1: added markup

Comment: Can we please see the CSS file?

Comment: This can be achieved through `Responsive Design` pattern.

Comment: Obviously. That's the entire point. He wants to use it for a responsive design...it's even tagged "responsive-design."

Comment: just to be clear, do you want it to work on pc or mobile or both?

Comment: @razzak yes, for smartphone as well.

Comment: can we do this only using css? or atleast least complicated jquery?

Comment: All the answers of this question are valid only if we keep sub menu visible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var menu = $("#nav-bar-filter"),
        subMenu = $(".subfilter"),
        more = $("#more-nav"),
        parent = $(".filter-wrapper"),
        ww = $(window).width(),
        smw = more.outerWidth();

    menu.children("li").each(function () {
        var w = $(this).outerWidth();
        if (w > smw) smw = w + 20;
        return smw
    });
    more.css('width', smw);

    function contract() {
        var w = 0,
            outerWidth = parent.width() - smw - 50;
        for (i = 0; i < menu.children("li").size(); i++) {
            w += menu.children("li").eq(i).outerWidth();
            if (w > outerWidth) {
                menu.children("li").eq(i - 1).nextAll()
                    .detach()
                    .css('opacity', 0)
                    .prependTo(".subfilter")
                    .stop().animate({
                    'opacity': 1
                }, 300);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function expand() {
        var w = 0,
            outerWidth = parent.width() - smw - 20;
        menu.children("li").each(function () {
            w += $(this).outerWidth();
            return w;
        });
        for (i = 0; i < subMenu.children("li").size(); i++) {
            w += subMenu.children("li").eq(i).outerWidth();
            if (w > outerWidth) {
                var a = 0;
                while (a < i) {
                    subMenu.children("li").eq(a)
                        .css('opacity', 0)
                        .detach()
                        .appendTo("#nav-bar-filter")
                        .stop().animate({
                        'opacity': 1
                    }, 300);
                    a++;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    contract();

    $(window).on("resize", function (e) {
        ($(window).width() > ww) ? expand() : contract();
        ww = $(window).width();
    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/XabcS/)

Had to modify CSS to make it work.
I didn't give static dimensions for any element so that the menu would be responsive regardless to it's contents.

How it works:
there are simply 2 functions `contract()` and `expand()`, when page load `contract()` will be called to move extra items to submenu, when window is resized if it's expanding `expand()` will be called and if it's contracting `contract()` will be called instead.

UPDATE:
added animation and fixed submenu location to the right, see the demo.

Comment: Thanks @razzak. Will include in my code. thanks for adding two functions contract and expand. it can be easily manage.

Comment: This works perfectly. But I want to fire the expand and contract function after scrolling 5px or so besides doing it on resize. Can you please tell me how we can do it? I want to do it reconstruct the menu items on scroll as well because the menu area is sticky and I scaled down the header section when it's sticky. So, we have more space left after scrolling.

Comment: when user resize and expand it's not working.

Answer (score 14):

Well, I've tried to build some script for doing it, here's what I've got:

```
$().ready(function () { 

    //we reconstruct menu on window.resize
    $(window).on("resize", function (e) {                                                   
        var parentWidth = $("#nav-bar-filter").parent().width() - 40;
        var ulWidth = $("#more-nav").outerWidth();                  
        var menuLi = $("#nav-bar-filter > li");                 
        var liForMoving = new Array();      
        //take all elements that can't fit parent width to array
        menuLi.each(function () {                       
            ulWidth += $(this).outerWidth(); 
            if (ulWidth > parentWidth) {
                console.log(ulWidth);
                liForMoving.push($(this));
            }
        });                         
        if (liForMoving.length > 0) {   //if have any in array -> move them to "more" ul
            e.preventDefault();                     
            liForMoving.forEach(function (item) {
                item.clone().appendTo(".subfilter");
                item.remove();
            });                         
        }
        else if (ulWidth < parentWidth) { //check if we can put some 'li' back to menu
            liForMoving = new Array();
            var moved = $(".subfilter > li");
            for (var i = moved.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //reverse order
                var tmpLi = $(moved[i]).clone();
                tmpLi.appendTo($("#nav-bar-filter"));
                ulWidth += $(moved[i]).outerWidth();
                if (ulWidth < parentWidth) {                                
                    $(moved[i]).remove();
                }
                else {
                    ulWidth -= $(moved[i]).outerWidth();
                    tmpLi.remove();
                }                           
            }                       
        }                       
        if ($(".subfilter > li").length > 0) { //if we have elements in extended menu - show it
            $("#more-nav").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#more-nav").hide();
        }
    });

    $(window).trigger("resize"); //call resize handler to build menu right
});
```

And [JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/3AU2N/1/)

Had to change your css styles to make it work properly. What we do is:

1. Get width of parent container, initial `width` of main menu is zero, but we probably have to show the additional menu, so we get its size as well.
2. On `window.resize` we loop through all elements in main menu (horizontal) accumulating each element width in the `ulWidth` variable.
3. Once the `width` of main menu is more than `width` of parent container -> we need to move the rest of menu items to the submenu (vertical) - so we push those elements to an array `liForMoving`.
4. If array `liForMoving` **isn't** empty - we clone its elements, append them to the submenu and remove them from the main menu.
5. If `width` of all elements in `mainMenu` is minor than the width of its container, we need to check if we can move some elements from the submenu to the main one
6. We iterate through submenu elements, grab each item, append to main menu (if you have different fonts and paddings in menus - final size of element will differ), check if its size is good to fit the parent container. If it **is** - we remove element from submenu (`$(moved[i]).remove()`), if **it's not** - we remove appended element (`tmpLi.remove()`)
7. Finally we check if the submenu has any items, and show/hide it.

Comment: Thanks thanks for jsfiddle demo. Looks good. Will integrate and see if its work in my local.

Comment: just make sure your css is correct to show it as it is in my fiddle (even w/o javascript code). I had some trubles there, so had to change almost all styles :D

Comment: awarding you bounty .. will comment on this if some more help require within your code. tx

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Have your jQuery detect how many terms in the `nav` bar have to be truncated. Then, add `li` elements to the `ul` by using the `document.createElement()` JavaScript method based on the number of terms truncated. For example, if your jQuery detects that 5 terms have been truncated, then use the following code:

```
var truncated_elements = 5;
for (i=1; i<truncated_elements; i++){
    var new_li = document.createElement('li');
    new_li.innerHTML = "truncated_term";
    document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].appendChild(new_li);
}
```

In the above code, the jQuery would figure out that 5 elements need to be truncated, and run a `for` loop in which it would create `li`s for each truncated element. The `innerHTML` of the `new_li` would be set to the content of the truncated element (using an array possibly), and then the `new_li` would be appended to the `ul` in the "More" submenu.

I can provide a JSFiddle/JSBin if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! I think this will only add those "LI" to "more" at once.

Comment: Actually, The `for` loop will keep adding `li` tags as necessary.

Comment: I can detail my answer more if necessary. Would you like a JSFiddle showing how this can be accomplished?

Comment: try using this code http://jsbin.com/flexmenu/2/edit. see if that can be done while resize.http://jsbin.com/flexmenu/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

I think the drop down menu should be reversed to keep the tab sequence in focusable items in the same order.

For accessibility you could also set the setsize and the position in the set. 
For accessibility reason I reset the focus to the cloned item when the moved element had focus and added setWaiAria to set the setsize and set position. And set the focus to the last item when the more link had focus and disappears. see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frontendplace/rvx26j1c/1/)

```
$().ready(function () { 

  var setWaiAria = function(menuLi){
    menuLi.each(function (i,el) {
      var $el = $(el);
      $el.attr('aria-setsize',menuLi.length);
      $el.attr('aria-posinset',i+1);
    });
  }

  // set wai aria aria-setsize and aria-posinset before cloning elements in other list
  setWaiAria($("#nav-bar-filter > li"));

  //we reconstruct menu on window.resize
  $(window).on("resize", function (e) {                         
    var parentWidth = $("#nav-bar-filter").parent().width() - 40;
    var ulWidth = $("#more-nav").outerWidth();          
    var menuLi = $("#nav-bar-filter > li");         
    var liForMoving = new Array();
    var activeElement = $(document.activeElement)[0];

    // before remove item check if you have to reset the focus
    var removeOriginal = function(item,clone){
      // check focused element
      if(item.find('a')[0] === activeElement){
        activeElement = clone.find('a')[0];
      }

      item.remove();
    }

    //take all elements that can't fit parent width to array
    menuLi.each(function () {
      var $el = $(this);            
      ulWidth += $el.outerWidth(); 
      if (ulWidth > parentWidth) {
        liForMoving.unshift($el);
      }
    }); 

    if (liForMoving.length > 0) { //if have any in array -> move em to "more" ul
      e.preventDefault(); 

      liForMoving.forEach(function (item) {
        var clone = item.clone();
        clone.prependTo(".subfilter");

        removeOriginal(item, clone);
      });

    }
    else if (ulWidth < parentWidth) { //check if we can put some 'li' back to menu
      liForMoving = new Array();

      var moved = $(".subfilter > li");
      for (var i=0, j = moved.length ; i < j; i++) { 
        var movedItem = $(moved[i]);

        var tmpLi = movedItem.clone();
        tmpLi.appendTo($("#nav-bar-filter"));


        ulWidth += movedItem.outerWidth();
        if (ulWidth < parentWidth) {
          removeOriginal(movedItem, tmpLi);
        }
        else {
          // dont move back
          ulWidth -= movedItem.outerWidth();
          tmpLi.remove();
        }

      }
    }           
    if ($(".subfilter > li").length > 0) { //if we have elements in extended menu - show it
      $("#more-nav").show();
    }
    else {
      // check if 'more' link has focus then set focus to last item in list
      if($('#more-nav').find('a')[0] === $(document.activeElement)[0]){
        activeElement = $("#nav-bar-filter > li:last-child a")[0];
      }

      $("#more-nav").hide();
    }

    // reset focus
    activeElement.focus();
  });

  $(window).trigger("resize"); //call resize handler to build menu right
});
```

Comment: Updated the example to a fiddle with a toggle menu. Opening the menu when a child of the menu has focus in:[fiddle version 4](http://jsfiddle.net/frontendplace/rvx26j1c/4/)