# Resize text based on div width

Tags: javascript, fonts, image-resizing, font-size

I'm looking for a solution for this that has more precision than breakpoints. I'm aware this will require JavaScript but I am having trouble finding a suitable plugin.

The majority of text on my site will stay the same, or I will simply adjust it with media queries (say 90% for tablet and mobile). That's fine, but I'm looking for a "real-time" solution" for areas such as my navigation menu and my banners.

[See the site here](http://www.haselden.co.uk/rttest/index.html)

You can see all my text is relative and sized using `ems` with a base font-size of 100%

If you resize the site you'll notice the menu "crashes" as the font size becomes too big. I'm keen to find a JS solution that will resize that text down relative to the width of the navigation bar so that I can always keep it all on one line (At mobile width, it'll go down into a collapsed menu)

Comment: If you're already using media queries, why not also add some rules that scale down the font size below a certain screen width? That's the clean solution, not adding some JS. Given that font sizes aren't really granular anyway (there's always a switch point from 11 to 10 pt, from 10 to 9 etc.) there's no point in implementing a 'sliding scale' solution anyway.

Comment: I see you have jquery so this should be easy. On an onresize event add something like $('someSelector').css('font-size', <some formula that has the with in it> + 'px').

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420151/manipulate-jquery-menu-on-re-size-for-responsive-layout/15592351#15592351

Answer (score -1):

Check out this jquery plugin

http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

It resized font-size and line-height based on element width.